# Passing wchar** into method behaves different

Tags: c++, winapi

In the following code when I comment     _tprintf( TEXT("PROCESS NAME:  %s\n\n"),*processName); I don't get output for main
_tprintf( TEXT("PROCESS NAME:  %s"),processName);

If not it prints correct output. I'm confused with it. Why does it behave like that? Any suggestions?

```
BOOL GetProcessImageNameFromPID::getProcessNameFromProcessID(DWORD processId,WCHAR**processName)
    {
        // here allprocessName is assigned
        if(pid == processId)
        {
            *processName = allprocessName;
            _tprintf( TEXT("PROCESS NAME:  %s\n\n"),*processName);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return( FALSE );
    }

    void main()
    {
    WCHAR* processName = (WCHAR*)malloc(sizeof(WCHAR));
        if(GetProcessImageNameFromPID::getProcessNameFromProcessID(580,&processName) == TRUE)
        {
            _tprintf( TEXT("***********\n"));
            _tprintf( TEXT("PROCESS NAME:  %s"),processName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using C++, so use a string class. Any string class. But don't spent hours looking for raw pointer mistakes. Life is too short. Seriously.

Comment: Also, don't use _T functions (like _tprintf and TEXT) unless you have a very specific need to support both Unicode and ANSI builds.  (Typically only necessary in frameworks or legacy projects.)

Comment: I think we need an MCVE.

Comment: You're allocating a single wide character, and then leaking that when you overwrite the pointer with whatever `allprocessName` points to.

Comment: There's really no helping some people. Take the advice above and re-write this code.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, because the answer the OP has accepted doesn't explain the behaviour described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format specifier for a wchar string is `%ls` and not `%s`.

Comment: Note however that `%s` will work if you're using `wprintf`.

Comment: @Janu: The fact that `%ls` works and `%s` does not work in your situation implies that `_UNICODE` is not defined in your project, causing `_tprintf()` to map to `printf()` (where `%s` expects `char*`) instead of `wprintf()` (where `%s` expects `wchar_t*`). `%ls` expects `wchar_t*` in both functions.